# $\triangle QQ_1Q_2 \sim \triangle AOP.$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let $P,Q$ be a pair of isogonal conjugates WRT $\triangle ABC$ with circumcircle $\odot(O).$ $AQ$ cuts $\odot(O)$ again at $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ is the reflection of $Q$ across $BC.$ Then $\triangle QQ_1Q_2 \sim \triangle AOP.$

The idea I had for this was to take a point L on A-altitude such that AOP is similar to QAL and show that QQ1Q2 and AQL are similar, but couldn't even go near the solution.

Comment: What's the source of the problem?

Comment: It was stated as a general lemma in a solution from AOPS without sol

Comment: Could you link the post on aops where this lemma was stated?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2459085